# Proper way to determine required authority in spring security access denied handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have an app where a user can have multiple roles/authorities. Whenever a user bumps into a url to which access is denied based on @Secured("role") annotations, I need to know why access was denied in the access denied handler (or actually the role(s) required to access the resource) so I can redirect the user to the appropriate page.

The parameters being handed to the access denied handler do not contain such information.

I could make a custom role-voter that would throw custom exceptions for which I could create custom error pages in web.xml, but somehow that does not feel like the correct approach to this situation.

What is the best approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom access decision manager, similar to the AffirmativeBased access decision manager:

```
public class ConfigAttributesIncludedInExceptionAffirmativeBasedAccessDecisionManager extends AbstractAccessDecisionManager
```

The code within is the same as the AffirmativeBased code (small class anyway) and instead of throwing an AccessDeniedException, I throw a custom AccessDeniedException.

```
throw new AccessDeniedExceptionWithConfigAttributes(messages.getMessage("AbstractAccessDecisionManager.accessDenied", "Access is denied"), configAttributes);
```

The custom access denied exception simply extends the AccessDeniedException class and has a property called configAttributes.

```
public class AccessDeniedExceptionWithConfigAttributes extends AccessDeniedException
{
private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 8733424338864969263L;

private Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes;

public AccessDeniedExceptionWithConfigAttributes (String msg)
{
    super(msg);
}

public AccessDeniedExceptionWithConfigAttributes (String msg, Throwable t)
{
    super(msg, t);
}

public AccessDeniedExceptionWithConfigAttributes (String msg, Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes)
{
    super(msg);
    this.setConfigAttributes(configAttributes);
}

public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getConfigAttributes()
{
    return configAttributes;
}

public void setConfigAttributes(Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes)
{
    this.configAttributes = configAttributes;
}
```

}

From there I can simply check in my AccessDeniedHandler class whether the AccessDeniedException is an instance of my custom exception class and if so, apply whatever logic I need to.

```
if(ade instanceof AccessDeniedExceptionWithConfigAttributes )
        {
            AccessDeniedExceptionWithConfigAttributes adeca = (AccessDeniedExceptionWithConfigAttributes ) ade;
            ...
        }
```

Works exactly how I want it to. However, if this is not the proper way to do this, I would like to hear it.